# Making sense of a marriage record from 1718 Schmie, near Maulbronn, Württemberg

Tags: 18th-century, wurttemberg

I have several questions about the attached image. It comes from the village of Schmie, near Maulbronn monastery in Württemberg, and is dated November 1718. (I am not sure I read the day correctly.)

[image: Marriage record of Paul Walter and Barbara Münzinger]

First, I need help transliterating one key word. Here is what I have:

"den 5(?) November (1718) wurden copuliert Hans Paulus Walter, H[ans] Mich[ael] Walters sel[ig] gew[esenen] Bürgers u[nd] ??? hinterl[assener] ehl[icher] Sohn    und    Margaretha, Christoph Münzingers sel[ig] hinterl[assene] ehl[iche] Tochter".

1. What is the word indicated with the questions mark in my transliteration attempt? I presume it ought to be a profession, but I have no clue how to read it. The last two characters in fact look Greek to me.
2. Is the mystery word a profession at all? I ask, because Schmie is unusual in that record keeping begins in 1694, previous records having apparently been destroyed. (Probably a French incursion, which were frequent at the time.) Unlike many other places, the local priest had enough sense to start with a Registry of Souls. Paul Walter was born in May or June 1693 (from his burial record), so his father should still have been alive at that time, but he is not included in the Registry of Souls. (There  are four entries: "Old" Hans Jacob Walter, born 1614,  who lived to the age of 95 and died in 1705, his son Hans Jacob Walter (born 1652), and Hans Jerg Walter (born 1659) and Hans Peter Walter (born 1662), both sons of a Michael Walter who died before 1693 and might have been Paul Walter's grandfather.)
3. Another possibility is that Paul Walter is not related to the others mentioned in the previous paragraph (Walter is a common enough surname). In this case, the description of Paul's father should include a place of origin. Could the mystery word in the image be such a place name?

Comment: Definitely difficult to read (I just tried in Archion, but the contrast is poor). I'm pretty sure the mystery word is a status or profession. It comes after "und" ("and"), and is an abbrevation (note the ":" after the w). The letter before the final w could be a "y", sometimes used for an "i", or maybe a "p"?

Comment: Do you have any more writing samples from the registry?
Since the priest is using so many abbreviations in this entry
he probably used similar abbreviations in the other entries. Maybe ink on other pages is better preserved.